# How to fix Samsung A8+ (SM-A730F)

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, odin

Hi, I'm trying to fix my Samsung A8+ (SM-A730F) and have no luck with it so far.

My phone suddenly freeze for almost 1 hour, then reset automatically and enter download mode and stuck in there until now.
I've searched for several solutions and ended up trying to install stock firmware.

Here's the list of thing I've downloaded:

- Odin3 v3.13.1 (from samsung odin website)
- Odin3 v3.14.4 (from technastic website)
- Samsung USB Driver v1.7.48.0
- Stock firmware A730FXXU3BRK3 (from samfrew website)
- Stock firmware A730FXXU7CTE1 (from samfrew website)
- Stock firmware A730FXXU7CUI2 (from samfrew website)
- TWRP v3.6.0

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I try to flash with each of stock firmware I downloaded using both Odin3 software (with and without administrator).
- I try to flash with all 4 BL, AP, CP, HOME_CSC files together
- I try to flash with only single file (BL only, AP only, CP only, HOME_CSC only)
- I try to re-partition with PIT files extracted from CSC files
- I try to flash TWRP (place it in AP section) without BL, CP, HOME_CSC files

Every attempt I try so far ended up with log message "Complete(Write) operation failed".
When I flash with TWRP log show "RQT_CLOSE" and phone displayed a text "Custom binary(RECOVERY) blocked due to remaining installment balance".

Any ideas, suggestion, or advice about how to solve this problem?

NOTES:

- I don't have original cable (currently use welcomm cable)
- I can't access my setting to know whether my developer and oem are enabled or not
- Sorry if I'm posting this in the wrong section

Comment: Though I dont think I can help you much here, but i would like to add two things: (a)The cable you're using DOES NOT matter, it needn't be original as long as it works. (b)Developer Options and USB debugging being turned ON or OFF ISN'T a CONCERN here. Neither Samsung's Download mode, nor stock/custom recovery cares that. The rest, let's hope someone comes up and helps you.

Comment: I see, I thought developer or usb debugging mode or cable matter. Yes, I hope someone will came up with something, it's kinda frustating to try and fail repeatedly while those solution found in the internet works.